# How do I run termux on my laptop?

Tags: android, termux

[Termux](https://termux.com/) is wonderful for getting the Unix experience on an Android device, but for development I really would like to have an emulator of Termux running on my GNU/Linux laptop. Maybe using Vagrant/Virtualbox?

How do I do that?

Comment: Install Android x86 in Virtualbox, install Termux in Android.  IIRC you need Marshmallow or a recent Lollipop to run Termux.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a bit late, but this is now rather easy with `podman`/`docker`. I prefer the former, but they are command-line compatible; so if you prefer the other, just `s/podman/docker`.

```bash
podman run -i -t --rm termux/termux-docker
# ^    ^   ^  ^  ^    ^
# |    |   |  |  |    |
# \------------------------ execute podman (or docker, whatever floats your goat)
#      |   |  |  |    |
#      \--------------+---- run the specified container
#          |  |  |
#          \--+------------ make it -i_nteractive and attach to t_ty
#                \--------- remove everything once we exit
# ………
# Now we're inside the termux shell; prove it does something useful:
~ $ pkg install parallel
~ $ seq 25 | parallel echo $$
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Remix OS](http://www.jide.com/remixos), which comes with Termux preinstalled.

Either run it from an USB stick or run it in Virtualbox.